# Conversion pt to mm or cm

Tags: conversion, plain-tex, lengths, unit-of-measure

Is there any way how to convert `pt` to `mm` or `cm` in plain TeX?

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-in-pt-etc-expressed-in-mm/

Comment: Sorry, the above was was LaTeX, not sure if any of it works in plain.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Well, the accepted answer there only requires a few basic LaTeX macros that are easy enough to copy from `latex.ltx`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It is not difficult to modify Philippe Goutet's solution to use eTeX only.

Comment: @Peter: Are we allowed to use the e-TeX extensions or does it have to be TeX82?

Comment: @Peter: All calculations can be done under Knuth TeX without eTeX extensions. But it needs much longer code using several registers.

Comment: @JosephWright: Does anybody outside of Stanford still use TeX90 instead of eTeX et.al.?

Comment: @MartinSchröder I have some contacts in chemistry publishing, for whom I wrote `achemso`. For that, e-TeX was not an option as it's not available on their server.

Comment: @JosephWright: And they can not upgrade? It's 2011...

Comment: @MartinSchröder I get the impression that the 'back end' publishers are happy with what works. It sounded as if an upgrade was possible but costly.

Answer (score 11):

To convert from a dimension given in points, save the dimension in a counter first, then do the conversion to what you need. When TeX saves the dimension in a counter it converts to `sp` units.

```
\catcode`@=11
\@tempdimb25.4mm 
\@tempcnta=\@tempdimb
\the\@tempcnta 
\divide\@tempcnta by65536\par 
\the\@tempcnta pt
\bye
```

Conversion from any unit to a point is a bit more involved:

```
\catcode`@=11
\newdimen\@tempdimb
\newcount\@tempcnta
\def\topoint#1#2{%
\@tempdimb=#1
\@tempcnta=\@tempdimb
\multiply\@tempcnta by10
\divide\@tempcnta by18647 \advance\@tempcnta by1
\multiply\@tempcnta by72 \divide\@tempcnta by2540
\expandafter\def\expandafter#2\expandafter{\the\@tempcnta}}

\topoint{25.4mm}{\test}

\test pt
\bye
```

Answer (score 10):

Expandable solution without eTeX, using Heiko's `bigintcalc` package. Really, this is a mess, and you should use one of the solutions which make use of the eTeX extensions.

```
\input bigintcalc.sty
\catcode`@=11

% Step 1: expand the number.
\def\pttocm#1{\romannumeral\expandafter\pttocm@i\romannumeral-`0#1pt;;;;}
\def\pttocm@i#1{\pttocm@clean\ifcat\relax#1\the\fi#1}
\def\pttocm@clean{\expandafter\pttocm@clean@\romannumeral-`0}
\def\pttocm@clean@#1{%
  \ifcase\ifnum`#1<"2B 1\else\ifnum`#1>"39 1\else 2\fi\fi
  \or\expandafter\pttocm@clean@end
  \or\expandafter\pttocm@clean@do\fi #1}
\def\pttocm@clean@do#1#2;#3;{\pttocm@clean#2;#3#1;}

% Step 2: convert the decimal number to an integer/10^n
\def\pttocm@clean@end#1;#2;{\pttocm@clean@end@#2.;#2;.;!}
\def\pttocm@clean@end@#1.#2;#3.#4;#5!{\pttocm@decimal#4.;;#1#4}
\def\pttocm@decimal#1#2;{\ifx.#1\pttocm@decimal@\fi\pttocm@decimal#2;0}

% Step 3: convert from pt to nm (25400000nm=7227pt)
\def\pttocm@decimal@#1;0#2;#3;{\fi
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pttocm@result
  \bigintcalcDiv{\bigintcalcMul{25400000}{#3}}{7227#2}.;}

% Step 4: check the sign
\def\pttocm@result#1{%
  \ifx-#1\expandafter\pttocm@result@neg
  \else\expandafter\pttocm@result@pos\fi#1}
\def\pttocm@result@neg-{\expandafter\pttocm@rmstop
  \expandafter-\romannumeral\pttocm@result@pos}
\chardef\pttocm@rmstop=0

% Step 5: shift the period 5 steps to the left, by reversing twice.
\def\pttocm@result@pos#1;{%
  \pttocm@reverse 00000#1%
  {?\pttocm@result@shift;}?;%
  {?\pttocm@result@print;}?;}
\def\pttocm@reverse#1#2;{%
  \pttocm@gobble#1%
  \pttocm@reverse#2;#1}
\def\pttocm@gobble#1{}
\def\pttocm@result@shift#1;#2;#3;#4.#5#6#7#8#9%
  {\pttocm@reverse #4#5#6#7#8#9.}
\def\pttocm@result@print#1;#2;#3;#4;{\pttocm@trimzeros{#4}}

% Step 6: remove spurious zeros.
\def\pttocm@trimzeros#1{\pttocm@trim@#1;\pttocm@trim@ 0;\pttocm@trim@@}
\def\pttocm@trim@#10;#2{#2#1;}
\def\pttocm@trim@@#1;#2;{\pttocm@trim@@@#1}
\def\pttocm@trim@@@#1{%
  \ifx0#1\else\expandafter\pttocm@trim@end\expandafter#1\fi
  \pttocm@trim@@@}
\def\pttocm@trim@end#1#2{%
  \ifx.#1\expandafter\pttocm@rmstop\expandafter0%
  \else\expandafter\pttocm@rmstop\fi #1}
\catcode`@=12

\pttocm{-12.1232pt}

\pttocm{283000000000}

\def\foo{23}
\pttocm{12\foo.1\foo2pt}

\newdimen\testdimen
\testdimen=1cm
\pttocm{\testdimen}

\testdimen=-1mm
\pttocm{\testdimen}

\bye
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a combination of Yiannis' question from [Stripping the pt from a dimension](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6262/1410) and Philippe Goutet's answer from [What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-in-pt-etc-expressed-in-mm/8337#8337):

```
\catcode`@=11
\begingroup
  \catcode `P=12  % digits and punct. catcode
  \catcode `T=12  % digits and punct. catcode
  \lowercase{%
  \def\x{\def\rem@pt##1.##2PT{##1\ifnum##2>\z@.##2\fi}}}
     \expandafter\endgroup\x%
\def\strip@pt{\expandafter\rem@pt\the}
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1\relax\relax}
\catcode`@=12
\convertto{mm}{10pt}
\bye
```

which requires e-TeX extensions.

Comment: And what about something without e-TeX extensions?

Comment: @Peter: Without e-TeX you need an extra assignment, which makes the macro non-expanable.

Comment: And what about some solution to convert `\the\hsize` to `mm`? Any ideas? `\catcode T=12` is not useful here.

Comment: You should terminate both `\dimexpr` with a `\relax`. Otherwise any dimen expression afterwards, like '* 10' will be taken as part of the inner `\dimexpr`. The `\relax` is removed by `\dimexpr` so you don't have to worry about expandable contexts.

Comment: @Peter: `\convertto{mm}{\the\hsize}` will work just fine. The catcode changes are only valid during the definition of the macro, not during the execution.

Comment: @Peter: What is your intention? Why do you need plain tex?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Why do you need Windows? Why do you need Linux? Why do you need Peugeot? Why do you need... `>:-/`

Comment: I agree with @MarcoDaniel. :) Thank you guys.

Comment: @morbusg: Maybe he want to create a command for a package and doesn't know the e-TeX macros or ... `;-)`. I think sometimes it easier to know the result. More users will find more ways ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately not everybody has "some-TeX" including the e-TeX extensions (yet).

Comment: @Stephen: I only know one distribution which doesn't come with e-TeX, that's the commercial Scientific Workbench. Are there more? The majority of users should have e-TeX.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Scientific WorkPlace, Scientific Word, Scientific Notebook of mackichan.com - and then there are all those users who depend on some administrator who just refuses to update some system originating from about 1492... ("We do not do updates. The users know and want the system as it is." Not even installing security patches for Windows...)

Answer (score 6):

With help of eTeX's `\scantokens`, `\strip@pt` can be also:

```
\def\strip#1.#2pt{#1\ifnum#2>0.#2\fi}
\def\convertto#1#2{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\strip
  \expandafter\expandafter\scantokens
  \expandafter{\the\dimexpr#2*65536/\number\dimexpr1#1\relax\relax\endinput}}

\convertto{pt}{1pc}

\bye
```