# What are the possible dimensions / sizes / units LaTeX understands?

Tags: dimensions, units, unit-of-measure, dimension-expressions

I know there are different ways of expressing sizes or dimensions in LaTeX such as points (`pt`), inches (`in`) and `ex`.

As some commands, such as `\hspace` [understand all of them](http://latex.computersci.org/Reference/SpacesAndSpacing#hspace), I would like to have a reference or complete list of possible dimensions or sizes including a description of what they mean.

Comment: The definitive reference is the TeXbook by Donald Knuth; the source of which is freely available.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

From the [plain TeX reference](http://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/Plain.html#dimensions):

- `pt`: Point
- `pc`: pica (12 `pt`)
- `in`: inch (72.27 `pt`)
- `bp`: Big point (72 `bp` = 1 `in`)
- `cm`: Centimeter
- `mm`: Millimeter
- `dd`: Didot point (1157 `dd` = 1238 `pt`)
- `cc`: cicero (12 `dd`)
- `sp`: Scaled point (65536 `sp` = 1 `pt`), the smallest TeX unit
- `ex`: Nominal x-height
- `em`: Nominal m-width

Available in math mode:

- `mu`: math unit, 1 `em` = 18 `mu`, where `em` is taken from the math symbols family, various lengths are derived from it (`thinspace`, `thickspace`, etc.)

Additionally available in pdfTeX and LuaTeX:

- `px`: "pixel", the dimension given to the `\pdfpxdimen` primitive; default value is 1 `bp`, corresponding to a pixel density of 72 dpi

See also here on TeX.SX:

- [What are the various units (ex, in, pt, etc.) expressed in mm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-in-pt-etc-expressed-in-mm)
- [Conversion pt to mm or cm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37316/conversion-pt-to-mm-or-cm)
- [Which measurement units should one use in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4239/which-measurement-units-should-one-use-in-latex)

The meanings of the various points are described here:

- [Wikipedia: Point (typography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you expand a little on Didot points and the meaning of the nominal in ex and em?

Comment: It is worth to note that "sp" is the smallest TeX unit and that it cannot be subdivided further. Thus any length in TeX is an integer multiple of "sp".

Comment: em: It is M-width

Comment: `pdftex` and `luatex` have also the `px` unit, whose value can be changed on a per document basis (default 1px = 1bp).

Comment: Thanks especially for the link to the great question `Which measurement units should one use in LaTeX?` It is especially illuminating (and questioning the m-wdith theory). That is all I wanted and fast (i.e., I will accept).

Comment: there's also the `mu` -- math unit (1 em = 18 mu, where em is taken from the math symbols family).  this can be used only in math mode.

Comment: I'm wondering why `pt` seems to be the default unit (see e.g. the [TikZ package manual](http://ctan.uib.no/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), chapter 13.2.1, where they explain that `2+3cm` becomes `2pt+3cm`), while it is almost the same as `px` and `px` *should* be the most native unit when compiling a document for on-screen view?

Comment: Wikipdia says 1 point = 1/72 inch, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29. What is the difference and relation between point and big point?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200934

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29#American_points. Roughly, the difference between a `pt` and `bp` comes from the definition of a foot. Historically, there were 864 points in a foot, but after the foot grew by a tiny fraction as a result of its definition in terms of a meter, the historical point was no longer exactly 1/72 of an inch, but slightly smaller. (`pt` uses one particular definition of a "printer's foot", as described in the Wikipedia article.) A `bp` is a slightly larger point, used also in PostScript, which is again simply 1/72 of an inch.

Comment: TeX was never designed for on-screen documents; it was designed for *resolution-independent* documents, which could be rendered by various printing equipment. A point is a well-defined unit, while pixel varies from screen to screen and may not have a consistent shape.

Answer (score 51):

I made visual overview for all units available in TeX. Including a comparison and the definitions/conversions.

[image: previwe]

The complete code and PDFs (EN, DE; b/w, color) are available at GitHub: https://github.com/tweh/tex-units

Comment: Oh my.... (+1) Some people do have too much time :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Actually _too much work_ to not procrastinate ;-)

Comment: I believe you have mislabeled the PostScript point:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21758/globally-redefining-1-pt-to-1-72-in-postscript-point-and-other-similar-changes

Comment: @Alan: Indeed … thanks! Don’t know where this mistake came from …

Comment: Are the `sp` values exact according to the TeXbook or source code?

Comment: @Crissov: The definition of `sp` is taken from “TeX by Topic”. The conversions are done on-the-fly wit LaTeX3 and may suffer from rounding errors.

Comment: Good job, thumbs up!

Comment: Amazing. The github source has a PDF version. Super useful, thanks!