# Beamer: Right Frame Border

Tags: beamer

How can I draw an e.g. 10px broad orange border on the right hand side of each frame? And how can I draw it only on the titlepage?

It shoud look like that:
[image: right frame border]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the beamer template `background canvas` and TikZ to do that:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author{diabonas}
\title{Frame border}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
{ % only on titlepage
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \fill[color=orange] (\paperwidth-10pt,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\maketitle
} % only on titlepage
\frame{Content}
\end{document}
```

[image: titlepage with right border]

This keeps the frame border local to the titlepage. To have it on all frames, remove the two lines marked with `% only on titlepage`.

BTW: The unit `px` is [only available in pdfTeX and LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41371/3323) - you can use `pt` instead which is the same as `px` in the default setting.

If you don't want to use TikZ, you can use the following background template (thanks to [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina)):

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    {\color{orange}\hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-10pt\relax}\rule{10pt}{\paperheight}}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect! Anyway, is there a way to do it without the tikz package?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Great, thank you! I do not want to use another package :-)