# Beamer Right and Left borders

Tags: beamer, border

I want to show a thick line on the left and right borders, i found the similar quetion here [Right border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48800/beamer-right-frame-border) but just for right border, here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}
\author{diabonas}
\title{Frame border}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
{\color{black}\hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-3pt\relax}\rule{10pt}{\paperheight}}%    
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}
\frame{Content}
\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want slides to look like this 
[image]

Comment: Replace `\paperwidth` with `0pt` in the question you cited?!

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner your suggestion make both side bars invisible

Comment: `\color{black}\rule{10pt}{\paperheight}\hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-20pt\relax}\rule{10pt}{\paperheight}` might do what you want to achieve.

Comment: I added an altered version of the cited question/answer. I just added the `left` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TYou set the background to be first a space of length `\paperwidth-3pt` and then a bar of `10pt` (of which only 3pt is visible). If you start with a bar of 3pt, then a space of length `\paperwidth-6pt` and the ending bar, it should be what you want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}
\author{diabonas}
\title{Frame border}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
{\color{black}\rule{3pt}{\paperheight}\hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-6pt\relax}\rule{10pt}{\paperheight}}%    
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}
\frame{Content}
\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use a 3 pt wide second rule as well?

Comment: @leandriis, good question. The easy answer is that it was like this in the question. Another view is that often filled areas at the border of the page can be made a bit bigger to guarantee no white small line at its end. In this case 7pt goes outside the page.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% Based on: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48800
\author{diabonas}
\title{Frame border}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
{ % only on titlepage
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \fill[color=orange] (\paperwidth-10pt,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    % Added
    \fill[color=orange] (0,0) rectangle (10pt,\paperheight);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\maketitle
} % only on titlepage
\frame{Content}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remove `{ % only on titlepage` and `} % only on titlepage` and it's on every page.