# double perpendicular symbol (for independence)

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I found from http://jblevins.org/notes/latex that I could use the independence symbol:

[image: X \independent Y]

> ```
> \newcommand\independent{\protect\mathpalette{\protect\independenT}{\perp}}
> \def\independenT#1#2{\mathrel{\rlap{$#1#2$}\mkern2mu{#1#2}}}
> ```

I was wondering how this works. Can anybody explain? I don't know the commands `mathpalette`, `rlap`, and `mkern2mu`.

Comment: The command \Perp from the package txfonts also works. (see http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

Comment: For those who is interested, this is the conditional independence symbol as explained [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2020/03/27/conditional-independence-notation/).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. `\mathpalette`: See [The mysteries of `\mathpalette`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/5764).
2. `\rlap`: This is referred to as a `r`ight over`lap`. That is, it makes a box of width `0pt`, and aligns the contents within to the left, similar to `\makebox[0pt][l]{<stuff>}`, causing the contents to overlap to the right.
3. `\mkern`: Kerning (or spacing) in math mode. The unit of measure is `mu` (or `m`ath `u`nits). So, `\mkern2mu` inserts a kern or space of `2mu` horizontally. For a take on these lengths (and others), see [What are the possible dimensions / sizes / units LaTeX understands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41370/5764)

Specific to your question about how this works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\independent{\protect\mathpalette{\protect\independenT}{\perp}}
\def\independenT#1#2{\mathrel{\rlap{$#1#2$}\mkern2mu{#1#2}}}
\begin{document}
$X \independent Y$ \par
$\scriptstyle X \independent Y$ \par
$\scriptscriptstyle X \independent Y$ \par

\bigskip

$X \independent Y_{X \independent Y_{X \independent Y}}$
\end{document}
```

The use of `\mathpalette` - defined internally as a specialized `\mathchoice` - allows the input to do defined in a way that captures the current math style. Note that there are four different math styles: `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`.

The above MWE shows how the single command `\independent` scales to regardless of where it's used, all because of a nifty use of `\mathpalette` and a helper macro `\independenT`. The helper macro captures the current math style and re-uses it inside an `\rlap`. The double use of the symbol is just for spacing purposes, adding to the `\mkern` insertion. That is, it sets the symbol `\perp` (of width `0pt` and `r`ight over`lap`), inserts of `2mu` kern (pushing the "cursor" to the right `2mu`s) and then inserts the symbol again. Since the symbol is set in the same style, the horizontal bar overlaps, but the vertical bar is spaced `2mu` apart. As a final take on mathematical spacing, the entire symbol is set as a relation using `\mathrel`.

Comment: What's the correct way to negate this (i.e. to add \not)?

Comment: @Adrian: Probably using [`centernot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot)'s `\centernot`...

Answer (score 52):

One can also use

```
 \newcommand{\ind}{\perp\!\!\!\!\perp}
```

It basically makes two orthogonal symbols very close to each other. The number of \! controls the space between each of the orthogonal symbols.
Thanks for all the helpful comments.

Comment: At the top of the file define:

\newcommand{\ind}{\perp\!\!\!\!\perp}

Comment: Simple and highly effective, and doesn't require packages that change other symbols. My favorite answer here!

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I found that the two $\perp$ symbols can become separated if they are right at the point of a line break! The fix is to make it a math atom: $\newcommand{\ind}{{\perp\!\!\!\perp}}$

Comment: @aaronsnoswell I think that messes up the spacing, so I use `\newcommand{\ind}{\mathrel{\perp\!\!\!\perp}}`.

Answer (score 18):

Simpler definition:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\indep}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\models$}}
```

Just turns `\models` symbol for 90 degrees. You can also try `\vDash`. It is smaller than `\models`

The code:

```
$X \indep Y$
```

The result:

[image]

For playing with vertical aligning use `\raisebox{}{}`

```
\newcommand{\indep}{\raisebox{0.05em}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\models$}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Simpler, but can one get the bar aligned with the bottom of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: I incorporated `\raisebox{}{}` in the answer for bottom  alignment

Comment: Simpler because poorer: to begin with, it is not treated as a relation, neither does it scale down in sub-/superscripts.

Comment: Amazing answer here!

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `\upvDash` symbol from the `mdsymbol` package. For more information please check [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://www.math.utk.edu/~finotti/sm14/m504/symbols.pdf)

The symbol looks like this

[image: upvDash]

Comment: Similar symbols are provided by the `MnSymbol` package, under the name `\upmodels`, and by the `fdsymbol` package, again under the name `\upvDash` (or `\Vbar`).