# Double perpendicular symbol in *KaTex* for notion

Tags: katex

This is for notion KaTex backend for math formulas. I'm aware of the question [double perpendicular symbol (for independence)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79434/double-perpendicular-symbol-for-independence) or others solutions for latex. But as notion does not support explicit library import nor defining function. Seems like it is impossible to use double perpendicular symbol in notion... Just in case anyone is aware and also wanted to type nicely done equation in notion.

Comment: Note that KaTeX just like MathJax is not related to LaTeX and friends (other that its capabilities to render certain parts of LaTeX syntax), thus your question is most likely off topic here.

Comment: `\mathrel{\bot\mkern-10mu\bot}` will do.