# Show the large image in latex beamer into four parts / transitions

Tags: beamer, graphics

I have a large image that I want to show in my presentation. I have four panels on the graph. What I want to do is in each slide, I want to show each panel. How do we show the certain portion of the image only at each time ?

For example I have a graph like this

[image]

How can I show each panel as full screen ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Remarks

When including an image using `\includegraphics` from the `garphicx` package (preloaded by beamer), then you can specify the options `clip` and `trim`, where `trim` takes additional parameters for the borders. In conjunction with `clip` the trimmed borders are cut off. When omitting `clip` only the borders are shift (i.e. the bounding box changes).

The `trim` parameters are

```
\includegraphics[clip,trim = left bottom right top]{...}
```

The units are `bp` (big point is 1/72 inch).

## Implementation

`Image111.png` is the file from your link, placed in the same directory.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Upper left}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[clip,trim=0 90 120 0]{Image111}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Lower left}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[clip,trim=0 0 125 90]{Image111}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Upper right}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[clip,trim=125 90 0 0]{Image111}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Lower right}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[clip,trim=125 0 0 90]{Image111}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Output (First slide)

> [image]

Comment: Would you please tell what are the units on trim parameters ?

Comment: The `trim` parameters are: `trim = left bottom right top`. The units are `bp` (big point is 1/72 inch).

Comment: One quick question: How can we know the total length of the of the image and width of the image in bp ?

Comment: I always use trial&error here. Calculating cutoffs in advance might be possible, but I don't think you will save time doing so. This post may also help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41370/what-are-the-possible-dimensions-sizes-units-latex-understands

Answer (score 3):

A TikZ solution that doesn't require manual specification of `trim` parameters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\scale{2}

\newcommand\clippic[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0]
    % extract dimensions of image
    \node{\phantom{\includegraphics[scale=\scale]{image111}}};
    \coordinate(nw)at(current bounding box.north west);
    \coordinate(se)at(current bounding box.south east);
    \coordinate(ne)at(current bounding box.north east);
    \coordinate(sw)at(current bounding box.south west);
    \coordinate(cent)at(current bounding box.center);

    % insert specific panel of image
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \clip[use as bounding box](#1)rectangle(cent);
    \node{\includegraphics[scale=\scale]{image111}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\makeframe[2]{
  \begin{frame}{#1}

    \centering
    \clippic{#2}

  \end{frame}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeframe{Top Left}{nw}
\makeframe{Top Right}{ne}
\makeframe{Bottom Left}{sw}
\makeframe{Bottom Right}{se}

\end{document}
```

You may also adjust the parameter of `\scale{}` to achieve scaling effect.

Comment: @ Kevin C Thank you for this solution. Works great.