# What are the unit of measurement in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, units, unit-of-measure

I want to know what are the units of measurement (of length) in `tikz` are available. I know that `pt`, `in`, `mm` like units are available , but what more are allowed in `tikz`?

I work sometimes with `qss` language and with `px` like units (in `tikz` this causes illegal unit of measurement).

Comment: The units are a tex primitive syntax, not tikZ, so this answer covers this question as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41370/what-are-the-possible-dimensions-sizes-units-latex-understands?rq=1