# Change spacing between table of contents and section

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I'm using TexStudio and I would like to know how to increase the distance between the Table of Content part of my document and the first section.

```
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section{Faktorregel}
```

I tried different ways of placing `\\[2cm]` but it didnt worked, also the other questions regarding spacing `\tableofcontent` all relate to spacing within the Table of Contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert vertical space using `\vspace{<len>}` where you specify `<len>` in any [appropriate dimension](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41370/5764) (or dimensions expression). For example, to insert a space of 5 typical lines, use

```
\tableofcontents

\vspace{5\baselineskip}

\section{A section}
```

There is also a starred version `\vspace*`, but that it typically used if you wish to force space that starts at the top of the page. Also, `\addvspace{<len>}` may be worth using, `add`ing `v`ertical `space` only *up to* `<len>`.