# How to correctly separate paragraphs with a blank line

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, paragraphs, white-space

I want to end a paragraph with a blank line and start a new paragraph.

When I use

```
first paragraph\\

second paragraph
```

I get an underfull hbox error.

When I use

```
first paragraph\par

second paragraph
```

It doesn't insert a blank line.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: What do you mean "end a paragraph with a blank line"?  A paragraph is a block of text.  Do you want a blank line after the paragraph ends?  Are you really wanting to have a bit more separation between your paragraphs?

Comment: @Teepeemm yes I want to separate two paragraphs with a blank line

Comment: And do you want the first line of each paragraph to get indented or not?

Comment: Please post a complete example. Are you using LaTeX? If so, does `parskip` do what you want? (Depends on your answer to @JoséCarlosSantos, probably.)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I know about `\noindent`. parskip doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: You can always use `\bigskip` or `\vspace{30pt}` or similar to have a certain amount of white space. If you want to have the same amount of white space after each paragraph, as already mentioned, `\parskip` is the way to go. // See e.g. here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Paragraph_indent .

Comment: @MS-SPO ah, now the parskip package works.. for some reason it didn't work earlier, maybe I didn't reload it correctly

Comment: Fine. However, `\parskip` is a length defined inside Latex, not a package. That said ... https://ctan.org/pkg/parskip ... but just use the length. // That's why we don't stop ASKING for complete MWE's ... ;-)

Comment: @MS-SPO there is a parskip package, but that seems to insert the `\parskip` length at every blank line in the tex file or something like that. I am now going with setting the `\parskip` length aswell, without the package.

Comment: Well, a blank in the tex file is a paragraph break, so you should expect a `\parskip` length at that point.  If you're getting `\parskip` where you think you shouldn't, then show us an example and we can talk about it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249

Comment: It's simply wrong to end a paragramp with `\\ `.  See [When to use `\par` and when ``\\``](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664) for more information Iand likely duplicate),  If you want an actual blank line, after a blank line in the input, add `\vspace{\baselineskip}` and then another blank line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton whats weird is that this is how it is usually taught all over the internet. Even the overleaf tutorial for linebreaks uses it as the top recommendation https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Line_breaks_and_blank_spaces Its all very confusing and frustrating, as it is a very common and supposedly "simple" operation.

Comment: @stimulate -- Thanks for the pointer to the Overleaf tutorial.  The information it gives is technically accurate, but woefully incomplete -- it should first introduce the concept of correct paragraph breaks, and only then introduce the exceptions.  I'll complain.  In the meantime, take a look at the paper I wrote for TUG'23 on "What every (La)TeX newbie should know" (https://tug.org/members/TUGboat/tb44-2/tb137beeton-basic.pdf).  I think it's not restricted, but if it is, please ping me with another comment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I get a request for a username and password so it is restricted. But thanks for all the great help on the ecosystem!

Comment: @stimulate -- If you send me email (tnt (at) tug (dot) org) I'll send you a pdf copy.

Comment: @barbarabeeton can't seem to send it to you, but its fine for now. I think I will find my way around.

Comment: @stimulate -- Ugh.  Somehow I typed it wrong.  (My laptop and I are having a "misunderstanding".)  The first part should be my initials, bnb .  Sorry about that.  The slides fro my talk might also be interesting (https://tug.org/tug2023/files/fr-04-beeton-newbie/beeton-newbie-slides.pdf) but the paper is organized better.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LaTeX separates paragraphs every time you add at least one empty line between texts. Then, how paragraphs are formatted depends on you. Here's a good helpful website: [How to change paragraph spacing in LaTeX](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_change_paragraph_spacing_in_LaTeX).

The length name `\parskip` controls extra spacing between all paragraphs in the document. In standard classes, it is set to `0pt` meaning no extra spacing is issued. For instance,

```
\setlength\parskip{6pt}
```

would cause LaTeX to add a distance of `6pt` between all paragraphs.

If you read through the website, you will come across the name `\baselineskip`, which hold a distance between two [baselines](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#character_boxes). Therefore,  `\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}` would separate paragraphs exactly by one empty line.

The macros `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, and `\bigskip` also add extra space in the place of issue but are meant for rather one-time usage. The amount of extra space they insert is held in three length names: `\smallskipamount`, `\mdeskipamount` and `\bigskipamount`. You could also use any of the names to insert `\<xxx>skip` between all paragraphs. For instance

```
\setlength\parskip{\bigskipamopunt}
```

would again add one empty line between all paragraphs.

Here's a small MWE to test paragraph skips:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}


\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

EDIT. BTW, `\\` is not a correct way to separate paragraphs. Use either `\par` or empty lines (which are converted to `\par`).

For an arbitrary skip, insert `\vspace{<length>}` where `<length>` is a unit length s.a. `12pt`, `1cm`, `3em` or `2ex` etc. (*). However, this macro will work between paragraphs. In order to add skip at the beginning of a document e.g. before the title, or at the top of a new page you should use a starred version `\vspace*{<length>}` (thanks for pointing at details in comments).

(*) Keep in mind there are fixed and relative unit lengths, some of which are consider horizontal and the other vertical (thanks to bring this in comments). I found a couple of answers which may help you to understand it e.g. check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4244/31283) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41371/31283).

Comment: Two suggested adjustments:  1) `\vspace*` also persists after a page break.  2) `em` is really a horizontal measure; `ex` is the corresponding (although not equal in distance) vertical measure.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for the suggestions. I added details to the answer.