How to use Times New Roman, 13 pt with bold section?
I'm working on my univeristy thesis and I've always thought that using latex should be easier for paging, fonts and so on. Actually, my specification are to use Times New Roman font 13 pt, but I can achieve it in any way. Also, I had some problem with chinese chars but it should be solved using xelatex as compiler.
I also have following layout settings:
 Page Setup
    Margins (left, right, top, and bottom) = 3 cm
    Header = 1.5 cm
    Footer = 1.5 cm
    Tab stops = 1.5 cm
    Binding = 1.5 cm
    Line spacing = body text = 1.5; footnotes = 1
    Font = Times New Roman; body text 13 pt, footnotes 10 pt

Paragraph Alignment
    Body text = justified
    Chapter title = centered and bold
    Paragraph title = justified

Page Numbering
    Pages are numbered with Arabic numerals (1, 2, 3…); the title page is not numbered (it is page 0); the numbering should be placed at the bottom right or center of the page.

Image's caption
    Italic, font 10 pt

I tried this:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}, headheight=1.5cm, footskip=1.5cm,    bindingoffset=1.5cm, footnotesep=1cm]{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left = 3 cm,
    right = 3 cm,
    top = 3 cm,
    bottom = 3 cm,
}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
%tab
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{left=1.5cm}
%times new roman
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
% font size 13
\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{scrextend}
% footpage size: 10pt
\usepackage{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
% chinese chars:
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK SC} 


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage{float}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\begin{document}
  
\title{
  \textbf{Thesis title}
}  
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
     
\newpage
\section*{First section}
Some text

\bigskip
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{pic1.jpeg}
\caption{\textit{text caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

But actually the output pdf is very different from the ones obtained by others tool which have other limitations.
Actually, main problems are that the font size doesn't seems to be 13 pt and the section titles are not bold. Also, using this font, I can't use italic or bold in my text, but I already checked the presence of bold and italic in my computer's font list.
Can anyone help me understanding my mistakes and how to solve them?
Thanks in advance.

In short: LaTeX pt are not same as points in word and the like. You need to use big points (bp).to get the same results. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41370/what-are-the-possible-dimensions-sizes-units-latex-understands and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)

So what should I do to not violate the layout rule?

Nothing! Those specifications usually mean: "Use a serif font in a reasonable (i.e. not too small, not too big) size." Nobody will measure the size of the letters or check if the font really is Times New Roman. I'd suggest to use noto for everything to keep it consistent
