# How much space is a line, vertically?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

How much space is a line, vertically ? E.g. something like "1.5em" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would typically be measured from the baseline of one line to the baseline of another, or given by `\baselineskip`, and depends on the font size loaded/specified as well as the font size current active. For example, with the following `\baselineskip`s are associated with the respective default font sizes loaded with the class:

- 10pt default font implies a 12pt `\baselineskip` (see [`size10.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size10.clo));
- 11pt default font implies a 13.6pt `\baselineskip` (see [`size11.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size11.clo));
- 12pt default font implies a 14.5pt `\baselineskip` (see [`size12.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size12.clo))

However, under a 11pt default font, [`\LARGE` sets a font at size 17.28pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764) with a `\baselineskip` of 22pt.
Conversion between lengths from points is discussed in [Conversion pt to mm or cm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37316/5764).

You can adjust this line spacing (or `\baselineskip`) by making a font selection

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\someText{And now follows some text to
show the distance of lines. The value is saved in \texttt{\textbackslash baselineskip}.}
\begin{document}
\the\baselineskip%%% The current distance between two baselines 
\vbox to 0pt {\hbox to 0pt {\textcolor{red}{\rule[0pt]{1cm}{\baselineskip}}}} \someText

\small\the\baselineskip
\vbox to 0pt {\hbox to 0pt {\textcolor{red}{\rule[0pt]{1cm}{\baselineskip}}}}  \someText

\tiny\the\baselineskip
\vbox to 0pt {\hbox to 0pt {\textcolor{red}{\rule[0pt]{1cm}{\baselineskip}}}}  \someText

\huge\the\baselineskip
\vbox to 0pt {\hbox to 0pt {\textcolor{red}{\rule[0pt]{1cm}{\baselineskip}}}}  \someText
\end{document}
```

[image]