# Separating a decimal number into whole and fractional parts with only the digits using pgfmath

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

Note: Firstly my apologies for making this confusing to start with. I have finally clarified matters I hope. This particular question is asking for macros that will split pgfmath results. The ones initially provided by egreg do just that. I am asking this question in a more general context [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142320/separating-a-decimal-in-any-format-into-integer-and-fractional-parts-in-basic-la).

I know how to do this in c++, it's easy, but it's not so clear how to do it in LaTeX. In this case I'm working with 'pgfplots' so I have access to the pgfmath routines and thus I don't have to worry about how to remove the `pt` as they do it for me already.

I want the whole digits with no trailing "." or ".0" and I want the fraction digits with no preceding "0.".

The following MWE shows my failed attempts at doing this.

**Output**:

[image: MWE Output]

**Code**:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=14mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9, /pgf/declare function={F(\x)=(\x+5)*(\x-1)*(\x-5);}}

\newlength{\printvar}

\newcommand{\intprint}[1]{\pgfmathparse{int(#1)}\pgfmathresult}
\newcommand{\fracprint}[1]{\pgfmathparse{frac(#1)}\pgfmathresult}

\newcommand{\truncprint}[1]{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\printvar}{#1}\pgfmathprint{\printvar}}
\newcommand{\diffprint}[1]{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\printvar}{#1}\pgfmathprint{#1-\printvar}}

\begin{document}
\par PGFMathParse F(1.5): \pgfmathparse{F(1.5)}\pgfmathresult
\par TruncPrint: \truncprint{F(1.5)}\quad DiffPrint \diffprint{F(1.5)}
\par IntPrint: \intprint{F(1.5)}\quad FracPrint \fracprint{F(1.5)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `pgfplotstable` package supports aligning numbers at their decimal separator. So does `siunitx`. Anyway, the easiest thing to separate int and frac part is using a delimited macro as in `\def\myMacro#1.#2\myEnd{And then you can use #1 (int) and #2 (frac).}`. (Something along those lines is used by PGFmath.) If you want to use that with lengths, you will need to remove the `pt` from `\the` which is already explained on TeX.sx. PGF also defines a few of those macros (`\pgf@sys@tonumber`, `\Pgf@geT`).

Comment: See also [Stripping the `pt` from a dimension](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6262) By the way,  PGFmath already defines `\pgfmathprint` which does the same as your `\numprint`.

Comment: I kind of have an answer but let me ask first. Do you want a completely package independent answer or can it depend on others? Such as the ones Qrrbrbirlbel(man that's a drag to type that) mentioned.

Comment: @GeoffPointer I wouldn’t use a space to delimit the stripping macros, this can be gobbled or something (I don’t know how this interact with a `\par`). In the case of `\pgfmathresult`, this is an [tag:expansion] problem, you will need to use `\expandafter\printplainbefore\pgfmathresult` (and here you won’t have the space you need). By the way, are you aware that `pgfplots` only uses PGFmath via TikZ via PGF? In your last case, you should be able to say simply `\usepackage{pgfmath}` instead of loading `pgfplots`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel (1) I'm currently happy with a solution using `pgf` because I'm doing a lot of work in `pgplots` with `axis` environments which is why I `\usepackage{pgfplots}`. None the less, I would ideally like a solution that doesn't use any `pgf' routines. (2) I tried your suggestion and it worked, but what do you recommend as suitable delimiter. I just used the letter m so I could try it out, but it looks ridiculous. But I guess you meant by \MyEnd, a macro that looks better in use and it doesn't matter too much what it actually is?

Comment: **1)** PGF routines? You can use PGFmath without PGF (but not vice versa). Of course, you can use `fp` or other math-related packages. **2)** Yes, usually, some form of macro is used because it can be “protected” from the user level by using `@` in its name. Nearly every character can do apart from `0-9.`, the space is a little bit too special for this and can cause troubles. PGFmath uses `\pgfmath@stop`. (And, indeed, its `int` function is defined as `\def\pgfmathint@@#1.#2\pgfmath@stop`, `frac` works similar but also must deal with integer input.)

Comment: I've clarified this question as a pgfmath only question and have moved other issues to separate questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do

```
\pgfmathparse{sqrt(2)}\printplainbefore\pgfmathresult.777
```

TeX follows instructions. It places `1.41421` as the replacement text of `\pgfmathresult` and proceeds expanding `\printplainbefore`; based on its definition, the first argument is `\pgfmathresult` and the second argument is `.777` as shown by TeX when setting `\tracingmacros=1`:

```
\pgfmathresult ->1.41421

\printplainbefore #1.#2 ->#1
#1<-\pgfmathresult
#2<-777
```

So you get `1.41421` as the result. Remember that TeX *never* expands tokens when it's absorbing arguments. If you do

```
\pgfmathparse{sqrt(2)}\expandafter\printplainbefore\pgfmathresult
```

you get an error, because of how you decided to delimit the second argument. Using a space as the final delimiter is usually a very bad choice.

Here's how one could do, assuming that the argument of `\printplainbefore` is always an explicit number or a control sequence expanding thereto:

```
\makeatletter
\def\printplainbefore#1{\expandafter\@printplainbefore#1..\@nil}
\def\@printplainbefore#1.#2.#3\@nil{#1}
\def\printplainafter#1{\expandafter\@printplainafter#1..\@nil}
\def\@printplainafter#1.#2.#3\@nil{#2}
\makeatother
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=14mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\makeatletter
\def\printplainbefore#1{\expandafter\@printplainbefore#1..\@nil}
\def\@printplainbefore#1.#2.#3\@nil{#1}
\def\printplainafter#1{\expandafter\@printplainafter#1..\@nil}
\def\@printplainafter#1.#2.#3\@nil{#2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\printplainbefore{1.41421} -- \printplainafter{1.41421}

\pgfmathparse{sqrt(2)}
\printplainbefore{\pgfmathresult} -- \printplainafter{\pgfmathresult}

\printplainbefore{1} -- \printplainafter{1}

\printplainbefore{.1} -- \printplainafter{.1}

\printplainbefore{0.1} -- \printplainafter{0.1}

\end{document}
```

You may want to add checks whether one of the two parts is empty, deciding to print `0` in this case.

[image]

Comment: This is a very instructive solution. Not only does it split my numbers, it's robust against input with missing bits, which saves a lot of my follow up questions. It taught me some important lessons about writing macros just when I was ready to learn them. Cheers

Comment: I received no notification that you had added this second more general solution. I have simplified this question so that it fits with your first answer which works with `\pgfmathresult`. If you look at the OP now, it and my MWE, are much more straightforward. Would you mind moving your second answer to [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142320/separating-a-decimal-in-any-format-into-integer-and-fractional-parts-in-basic-la)?

Comment: @GeoffPointer Done.