# Separating a decimal in any format into integer and fractional parts in basic LaTeX

Tags: macros

**Note**: I've separated this question from what was becoming a very tangled discussion. I know egreg already has a solution, so I'll just wait until he posts it here.

**Question**: The solution has to take a decimal number in any form, that is, a dimen/length variable, a plain `\def`, a number string, whatever and use only basic LaTeX to separate out the integer part and only the digits of the fractional part without preceding "." or "0." leaving the user of said solution to then format these results any way they like.

The related question using `pgfmath` is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141722/separating-a-decimal-number-into-whole-and-fractional-parts-with-only-the-digits). The `pgfmath` routines chop off the `pt` for you. In that case you only need a macro that either reads `\pgfmathresult` or similar.

[image: Answer code output]

My MWE presents a limited solution that I came up with using help from E.Ellett and egreg before they knew just how general I wanted this. It provides two routines that read a length variable, that is, one declared with `\newlength{\thelength}`, but as pointed out by egreg, it still has only limited expanding ability.

**MWE Code**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\makeatletter

\def\my@get@length#1{\edef\pure@length{\strip@pt#1}}

\def\printplainbefore#1{\my@get@length#1\expandafter\@printint\pure@length..\@nil}
\def\@printint#1.#2.#3\@nil{#1}
\def\printplainafter#1{\my@get@length#1\expandafter\@printfrac\pure@length..\@nil}
\def\@printfrac#1.#2.#3\@nil{#2}

\makeatother

\newlength{\thislength}
\setlength{\thislength}{123.456pt}
\tracingmacros=1

\begin{document}
The: \the\thislength\quad
Split: \printplainbefore{\thislength} -- \printplainafter{\thislength}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I was coming back to do what you just did. I was in the middle of a three post editing juggle to clarify this situation. You don't let the moss gather do you? ;-) Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an extended version of the macros proposed in [Separating a decimal number into whole and fractional parts with only the digits using pgfmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141722/separating-a-decimal-number-into-whole-and-fractional-parts-with-only-the-digits) that accepts as argument to `\printplainbefore` and `\printplainafter` also a length or skip parameter or a macro that expands to a length (see the last call with `\test`). I used `\dimexpr`, so e-TeX is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\catcode`P=12 \catcode`T=12 \lowercase{\endgroup

\def\printplainbefore#1{%
  \expandafter\geoff@strip@pt\expandafter\@printplainbefore\the\dimexpr#1PT\relax\@nil
}
\def\printplainafter#1{%
  \expandafter\geoff@strip@pt\expandafter\@printplainafter\the\dimexpr#1PT\relax\@nil
}
\def\@printplainbefore#1.#2.#3PT\@nil{#1}
\def\@printplainafter#1.#2.#3PT\@nil{#2}

\def\geoff@strip@pt#1#2PT#3\@nil{#1#2..PT\@nil}

} % balance the open brace after \lowercase
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\printplainbefore{1.41421} -- \printplainafter{1.41421}

\pgfmathparse{sqrt(2)}
\printplainbefore{\pgfmathresult} -- \printplainafter{\pgfmathresult}

\printplainbefore{1} -- \printplainafter{1}

\printplainbefore{.1} -- \printplainafter{.1}

\printplainbefore{0.1} -- \printplainafter{0.1}

\printplainbefore{\baselineskip} -- \printplainafter{\baselineskip}

\printplainbefore{\medskipamount} -- \printplainafter{\medskipamount}

\printplainbefore{12.34pt} -- \printplainafter{12.34pt}

\def\test{12.34pt}

\printplainbefore{\test} -- \printplainafter{\test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### NOTE

With this generalized macro it's impossible to distinguish the case where the integer or fractional part is empty. So `\printplainbefore{.1}` and `\printplainbefore{0.1}` will give the same result `0`.

Comment: I've read a page [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/what-are-benefits-of-e-tex-for-latex-users) about e-TeX and I'm still confused about the difference between it and `etex.sty`. Is that stuff now just a part of `LaTeX2e`? You're saying `e-TeX` is needed but the code works for me without any explicit `usepackage` call.

Comment: e-TeX is the engine that's been in use since some years. LaTeX doesn't use the provided extensions, but several packages do.

Comment: Does saying e-TeX is the engine mean I can use it's functionality without any `usepackage` calls? I still have a lot to learn about how LaTeX uses TeX. I have Knuth's TeXbook and I'm making some progress with it - it's basically all about understanding how TeX converts raw source into tokens and then how it expands them - yes?? But I still have to learn what TeX you can use and what you can't within LaTeX. EG - I learnt the hard way that you can't use registers directly. Lamport's LaTeX:ADPS2ed is on it's way in the post, will that be a good start?

Comment: Yes, you can use the new primitives like `\unexpanded` or `\dimexpr` in any LaTeX document. However, in order to access the extended register pool you have to `\usepackage{etex}`.

Comment: Any thoughts about the rest of my comment?

Comment: @GeoffPointer Lamport's book is the “official” user manual for LaTeX; it doesn't even touch programming in LaTeX. What do you mean by “you can't use registers directly”?

Comment: I used TeX for some time before moving to LaTeX. I was used to doing things like `\countdef\nstep=81`. I wrote my first routines in LaTeX this way and was perplexed by my variables seemingly changing at random and the failure of my algorithms that I was sure were correct. I then discovered `\newcounter{nstep}` and everything was fine.